# randomForestSRC predicted values

Tags: r, random-forest

I've been trying to use the R package 'randomForestSRC' to predict some stuff, but after running 'rfsrc' and 'predict.rfsrc'. Both have a return called predicted, but the predicted values don't seem to correlate with any of my values. Does anyone know what these predicted value are?

The commands I run: (this is from their examples on the documentation)

```
data(veteran, package = "randomForestSRC")
train <- sample(1:nrow(veteran), round(nrow(veteran) * 0.80))
veteran.grow <- rfsrc(Surv(time, status) ~ ., veteran[train, ], ntree = 100)
veteran.pred <- predict(veteran.grow, veteran[-train , ])
```

The predicted values:

```
veteran.pred$predicted
[1] 49.96350 58.45100 38.28317 63.17000 67.56917 57.45633 66.23733 54.81967 72.60817 47.71083 43.94983 37.85000
[13] 41.80333 47.84233 85.81488 70.49050 92.45600 70.95321 85.63933 45.38833 66.74655 76.46067 52.68717 68.90750
[25] 85.17983 43.31617 48.80267
```

Comment: The values do not seem strange to me, if you check the `summary`, the statistical values are not so distant, and its `n` is relatively small.

Answer (score 0):

The predicted values from both `rfsrc` and `predict.rfsrc` are the predictions based on all the trees built, using the training data and testing data respectively.

```
#In-bag predicted value for the first case in training data
veteran.grow$predicted[1]
> 80.56843

#Prediction based on all trees for the same case
predict(veteran.grow, 
        newdata=veteran[train[1],])$predicted
> 80.56843
```

The `rfsrc` also returns [out-of-bag prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-bag_error) as `predicted.oob`. Which is based on the trees that the case was not used in the building process. For example, if case 1 was used in trees 1 to 30, the OOB prediction for case 1 would be based on trees 31 to 100, instead of all the trees.

```
#Keeping the info about nodes of each tree
veteran.grow <- rfsrc(Surv(time, status) ~ ., veteran[train, ], ntree = 100, 
  membership=T)

#Out-of-bag predicted value for the first case
veteran.grow$predicted.oob[1]
> 72.88305

#Prediction based on the trees that case 1 was not included in
ind = which(veteran.grow$inbag[1,]==0)
predict(veteran.grow, 
        newdata=veteran[train[1],], 
        get.tree=ind)$predicted
> 72.88305
```

Comment: great answer! can you please take a look at my question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66684292/r-plot-individual-predictions thank you!

Comment: The answer is not relevant to the question. The question is what is the "predicted" value rather than how to get predicted value. The answer should be is it "predicted median survival time" or "predicted probability of survival at some time point" or something else?

Comment: According to the randomForestSRC manual, the predicted values from the forest (predicted and predicted.oob) for survival are as follows:
a vector of mortality values representing estimated risk for each individual calibrated to the scale of the number of events (as a specific example, if i has a mortality value of 100, then if all individuals had the same x-values as i, we would expect an
average of 100 events).